# How to create Domain class Instance in Grails?

Tags: grails

I have two Domain class in grails

```
class Quotation {

    static searchable =true
    static constraints = {
        referenceNo(nullable:true)
        dateOfRequest(validator: {return (it <= new Date())})
        number(blank:false)
        estimatedHours(nullable:true, blank:false, min:0)
    }

    int referenceNo;
    Date dateOfRequest;
    String number="11-120001Q01";

    int estimatedHours; 
    String toString(){
        return number   
    }   
}


class Project {

    static constraints = {
        projectID(blank:false,nullable:false)
        number(blank:true,nullable:true)
        projectManager(blank:false)
        teamLeader(blank:false)
        teamMembers(blank:false)
        sizeOfTeam(blank:false)
        status(inList:["active", "closed"])
    }

    String projectID
    Quotation number
    String projectManager
    String teamLeader
    String teamMembers
    Integer sizeOfTeam
    String status
}
```

i want to print number and estimatedHours from Quotation class to be in Project class but it is only showing number.Can any one please tell me how to create an instance of Quotation in Project class and call the getter and setter methods of Quotation class?

Comment: It's as simple as using ordinary Java. What is your code and what do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to create Domain first and when i go to Project creation page then number and estimatedHours field of Quotation class should be displayed on Project creation page.

Comment: Are you trying to create Project instance based on number and estimatedHours of Quotation ??